# Centralizar menu na página

Tags: css

Estou tentando alinhar o menu que tenho de forma centralizada, mas as tentativas que fiz foram frustradas e meu conhecimento em `css` é pouco, o tentei foi fazer alterar isso aqui:

```
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu {
    position: unset;
}
```

O código do css é esse:

```
/** Menu
 **************************************************************** **/
#topBar {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fff;
    min-height:30px;
    z-index:11;
}
body.boxed #topBar {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#topNav a.logo {
    padding:30px 0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    z-index:10;
}
#topNav a.logo.onepage {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:3px;
}
#topBar a.social {
    width:24px; height:24px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-size:16px;
}

#topNav {
    display:block; left:0; right:0; top:0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
         -o-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
            box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}


#topNav .nav-pills>li>a, 
#topNav .nav-pills>li>a:hover, 
#topNav .nav-pills>li>a:focus,
#topNav .nav-pills>li.active>a, 
#topNav .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, 
#topNav .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    background-color:transparent;
}
#topNav div.navbar-collapse {
    padding:0;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li {
    color:#666;
    border-left:#eee 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li:last-child {
    border-right:#eee 1px solid;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li:hover>a:before,
#topNav ul.nav>li.active>a:before {
    content:' ';
    background-color: #EF4539;
    height: 2px; width: 100%;
    left: 0; top: -3px;
    position: absolute;
}

#topNav ul.nav {
    border-right:#eee 1px solid;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li a {
    color:#000000;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    display:block;
    font-weight:300;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s;
            transition: all 0.2s;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li>a>span {
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ccc;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s;
            transition: all 0.2s;
}

#topNav ul.nav>li:hover a {
    color:#333;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li:hover a>span {
    color:#888;
}



/* submenu */
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu li.divider {
    margin:-1px 0 0 0;
    padding:0; border:0;
    border-bottom:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 1px solid;
}
#topNav .nav li:hover>ul.dropdown-menu {
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
}

#topNav ul.dropdown-menu {
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:0;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:#eee 1px solid;
    border-top:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 6px 12px;
    min-width:200px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
}
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu li {
    position:relative;
}
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu>li a {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-weight:400;

    color:#555;
    font-size:13px;
    border-bottom:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 1px solid;
}
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu>li a i.fa {
    margin-right:4px;
}
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: "\f105";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 9px;
    color:#999;
}

#topNav .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #eaeaea;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
#topNav .dropdown-submenu li:hover> a:after {
    color:#fff !important;
}
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child>a {
    border-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li:hover>a, 
.dropdown-menu>li:focus>a {
    color:#fff !important;
    background-color:#333;
}

/* sub-submenu */
#topNav ul.dropdown-menu>li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%; top:0;
    padding:0; margin:0; 
    border-top:0 !important;
    border-bottom:0 !important;
    border-right:0 !important;

    border:#eaeaea 1px solid;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
}

/* search */
#topNav form.search {
    float:right;
    max-width:180px;
    margin:12px 8px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
#topNav form.search {
    position:relative;
}
#topNav form.search input {
    padding:6px 26px 6px 6px;
    height:auto; width:100%;
    font-size:13px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
}
#topNav form.search button {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; right:10px;
    color:#ccc;
    z-index:1;
}





/* mobile */
#topNav button.btn-mobile {
    display:none;
}
    #topNav button.btn-mobile {
        color:#fff;
        display: none;
        background:#333;
        padding:6px 10px;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:3px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
           -moz-border-radius: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
    }   
    #topNav button.btn-mobile i {
        padding:0; margin:0;
        font-size:21px;
    }



/** Mega Menu
 **************************************************************** **/
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu {
    position:inherit;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu p {
    margin:0; padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:13px;
}

#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div.row {
    width:100%;
}

#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div {
    display:table;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div div {
    border-left:#eee 1px solid;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div div:first-child {
    border-left:0;
}

#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul {
    width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul.dropdown-menu>li {
    margin:0 15px; padding:15px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: #eee 1px solid;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 6px 12px;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul ul {
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    list-style:none;
}

#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu h3 {
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin:10px 10px 20px 10px; padding:0;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul li>a {
    border-bottom:0;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul li.active>a,
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul li:hover>a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#333;
}
#topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul li.divider {
    border:0;
    border:rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1px solid;
    margin:10px 0;
}





/** Secondary Main Menu
    Top Bar / Shop Cart
 **************************************************************** **/
#barMain {
    float:right;
    margin-top:6px;
    font-size:12px;
}

#barMain .nav>li>a {
    padding:5px 10px;
}
#barMain .nav>li>a:hover, 
#barMain .nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}

/* cart */
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart {
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#topBar.styleBackgroundColor .nav>li.quick-cart {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
}
#topBar.styleBackgroundColor .nav>li.quick-cart.open>a {
    color:#000;
}
#topBar.styleBackgroundColor .nav>li.quick-cart p {
    color:#000;
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart>.dropdown-menu {
    border:0; margin:0;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    width:185px;
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart .quick-cart-content {
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart p {
    margin:0; padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:13px;
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart a.quick-cart-item {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    min-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 1px solid;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart a.quick-cart-item,
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart a.quick-cart-item a {
    color:#999 !important;
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart a.quick-cart-item:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}
#barMain .nav>li.quick-cart .cart-footer {
    margin-top:10px;
}





/** Responsive Top Nav
 **************************************************************** **/
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        max-height:100%;
    }
    #topNav .container {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #topNav button.btn-mobile {
        display:block;
        float:right;
        margin-right:15px;
    }

    #topNav form.search {
        float:left;
        margin-top:6px;
        margin-left:15px;
    }

    #topNav nav.nav-main {
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse,
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse.in {
        width: 100%;
        margin:50px 0 0 0;
    }
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse {
        float: none;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    #topNav div.nav-main-collapse {
        position: relative;
    }


    #topMain>li>a>span {
        display:none !important;
    }
    #topMain li {
        display:block !important;
        float:none;
        text-align:left;

        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
           -moz-border-radius: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
    }
    #topMain>li>a {
        text-align:left;
        border:0;
        border-bottom:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 1px solid;

        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
           -moz-border-radius: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
    }
    #topMain>li:hover,
    #topMain>li:hover>a {
        border-top:0 !important;
    }

    #topNav ul.nav>li>a:after {
        content: "\f107";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 14px;
        right: 20px;
        top: 15px;
        color:#999;
    }

    /* submenu */
    #topMain ul.dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        display: none !important;
        border-left:0 !important;

        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
           -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
    }

    #topNav nav.nav-main li.resp-active > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block !important;
        margin-left:30px;
        margin-right:30px;
        padding:20px 0;
        border-right:0;
    }
    #topNav nav.nav-main li.resp-active > ul.dropdown-menu li {
        border-left:0;
    }

    #topNav ul.nav>li:hover>a:before, 
    #topNav ul.nav>li.active>a:before {
        background-color:transparent;
    }

    #topNav ul.dropdown-menu>li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        position:static;
    }

    /* mega menu */
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul.dropdown-menu>li {
        padding:0; margin:0 30px 0 0;
        border:0;

        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
           -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;   
    }
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu h3 {
        margin-left:8px;
    }
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu>ul li>a {
        border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 1px solid;
    }
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div,
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div div {
        border:0; margin-bottom:30px;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
    #topNav ul.nav>li.mega-menu div div:last-child {
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

    #topNav form.search {
        margin-left:4px;
    }
    #topNav button.btn-mobile {
        margin-right:4px;
    }

    #topBar a.logo {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        margin:6px 0;
        float:none;
    }

    .hide_mobile {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

A página com o menu pode ser vista aqui:

[Projeto](http://www.fbnexport.com/)

Comment: Adicione um `width` em `#topNav ul.nav`, acredito que deve resover.

Comment: Adiciono com algum valor específico @RubensBarbosa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso resolveu o problema aqui no Chrome. Com `float:left` vc não ia conseguir alinha no centro...

```
#topNav ul.nav>li {
    color: #666;
    border-left: #eee 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-pills>li {
    /* float: left; */
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu meu problema @hugocls, grato.

Comment: @adventistapr que bom que resolveu. Mas.... Depois que vc ajustar sem o float etc , vai ficar faltando um pedaço do border da nav, pq vc só usou border-right, vc vai ter que corrigir isso por estática apenas... ou então retira a borda da direita tb...

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 4):

```
#topNav ul
{
   display: block;
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: quebra o menu em duas linhas (contato vai pra linha debaixo)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo só aumentar o tamanho do menu width: 650px;

Comment: blz, dá certo, mas como sabes que deve ser 650px?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Só testando pelo tamanho dos itens do menu. Se o menu for dinâmico essa pode não ser uma boa opção.

Comment: Na verdade o menu já está centralizado, só que ao lado do item `CONTATOS` parece ter um item vazio, talvez a largura da div ou ul, sei lá

Answer (score -3):

Vou deixar algumas dicas para centralizar elementos HTML

Usando  display flex no elemento pai:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.elemento-centralizado {
  /* Estilos adicionais para o elemento */
}
```

Usando margin auto no left e right:

```
.elemento-centralizado {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Usando position absolute:

```
.elemento-centralizado {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```